# Remove Cache or turn off cache for a Individual block in Magento for full page cache Hole Punch

Tags: magento-enterprise

in some case few block need to be dynamic if you use full page at that time we need to turn off cache only for that Individual  block
for that we call Hole Punch

to do that follow below steps       
                                           1. create cache.xml  file in AW/Zblocks/etc/cache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <placeholders>
        <deptlhpromo>
            <block>core/template</block>
            <template>zblocks/deptlhpromo.phtml</template>
            <name>deptlhpromo</name><!-- THIS MUST MATCH THE ALIAS IN THE LAYOUT XML EXACTLY -->
            <placeholder>DEPTLHPROMO</placeholder>
            <container>AW_Zblocks_Model_Container_Deptlhpromo</container>
            <cache_lifetime>86400</cache_lifetime>
        </deptlhpromo>
    </placeholders>
</config>
```

2. Create Container model that is AW/Zblocks/Model/Container/Deptlhpromo.php

```
class AW_Zblocks_Model_Container_Deptlhpromo extends Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Abstract
{
    protected function _getCacheId()
    {
    return 'DEPTLHPROMO_' . md5($_COOKIE["frontend"]);
    }

    public function applyInApp(&$content)
    {
        $block = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('block');
        $template = 'zblocks/deptlhpromo.phtml';

        $block = new $block;
        $block->setTemplate($template);
        $block->setLayout(Mage::app()->getLayout());    

        $blockContent = $block->toHtml();

        $this->_applyToContent($content, $blockContent);

        return true;
    }

    protected function _saveCache($data, $id, $tags = array(), $lifetime = null)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

3. Create phtml which will called once page is cache else it will call default xml (in our ex it will be from catalog.xml)/template/zblock/deptlhpromo.phtml

   echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('zblocks/block')->setPosition('DEPT_LH_promo')->toHtml();

4. catalog.xml where default loaded if page is not cache that is at first time

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view-category.phtml">  
                <block type="core/template" name="deptpromo">
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <template>zblocks/deptpromo.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                </block>     
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
         </catalog_category_default>
```

Imp Note :- in catalog.xml block name should be same as in cache.xml place order  that is

```
    should be same as 


<config>
            <placeholders>
                <deptlhpromo>
                    <block>core/template</block>
                    <template>zblocks/deptlhpromo.phtml</template>
                    <name>deptlhpromo</name><!-- THIS MUST MATCH THE ALIAS IN THE LAYOUT XML EXACTLY
```

then only it works

Comment: Please add question first, to which this post serves as an answer, and then add this post as the answer. This is how SE works.